# How to efficiently write multiple data ranges from one file on the internet simultaneosly into one File

Tags: c#, filestream, networkstream

I want to have multiple network stream threads writing/downloading into one file simultaneosly.
So e.G you have one File and download the ranges:
0-1000
1001-2002
2003-3004...
And I want them all to write their receiving bytes into one File as efficient as possible.

Right now I am downloading each range part into one File and combine them later when they are all finished into the final File.

I would like them to, if it is possible to all write into one File to reduce disk usage and I feel like this could all be done better.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: It's very hard to advise you on how to improve your current solution without seeing your current solution. For example, I don't understand why you can't simply seek (not necessarily for the file on the "Internet" - http? - but certainly for the local file).

Comment: It is one file on the internet, but it is large and it would be faster to download many parts of it simultaneosly

Comment: That's not a duplicate because the accepted answer is most certainly not efficient, it locks before writing each range.

Answer (score 0):

You could use persisted memory mapped files, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files

> Persisted files are memory-mapped files that are associated with a source file on a disk. When the last process has finished working with the file, the data is saved to the source file on the disk. These memory-mapped files are suitable for working with extremely large source files.